# Emploi de « qui ça »

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

Quand peut-on utiliser la tournure interrogative « qui ça ? ».

J'imagine qu'il s'agit d'un raccourci alternatif de la question « qui a fait ça ? » ou « qui a dit ça ? » mais je me demande s'il y a d'autres emplois.

Est-ce une tournure à éviter ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

« **Qui ça ?** » n'est pas vraiment l'équivalent de « **Qui a fait/dit ça** ? » mais est essentiellement utilisé à l'oral, soit pour demander à quelqu'un de répéter le nom d'une ou plusieurs personnes qui viennent d'être mentionnées et dont on n'a pas bien compris le nom, soit pour demander le nom de la ou les personnes dont il vient d'être question. ***Ça*** est ici un pronom qui se réfère à ce qui vient d'être dit. Il est utilisé dans les questions sans verbe suivantes (toutes reprises du commentaire de @Greg) :
  ***Quand ça** ?

  **Où ça ?**

  **Quoi ça ?** (belg.)*

On le trouve aussi dans d'autres questions averbales où on ne demande pas de répéter mais simplement d'en dire davantage, de développer le sujet :
  **Pourquoi ça ?**
  **Comment ça ?**

Je ne vois aucune raison de l'éviter mais en langage soutenu, qui tolère peu le pronom ***ça***, on se contenterait peut-être de « **Qui ?** » ou on pourrait dire « **De qui parlez-vous ?** », « **De qui s'agit-il ?** », « **Qui donc ?** » voire le très (trop) soutenu  « **Qui cela ?** ».

Comment: On peut aussi noter que ce "ça" qui renforce l'interrogation peut être utilisé avec d'autres pronoms interrogatifs: quand ça ?, où ça ?, pourquoi ça ?, quoi ça ?, comment ça ?

Comment: @Greg Très juste. On peut ajouter que *Quoi ça ?* n'est pas utilisé en France (on dira *De quoi ?*, *T'as dit quoi ?*, etc.). Le français de Belgique utilise aussi couramment *Quoi dit ?* inconnu ailleurs.

Comment: Comment ça ? On dit pas "quoi ça" en France ??? Merci, encore un belgicisme à ma collection ! Note qu'on écrit "quoi, dis ?", le "dis" est un impératif 2eme personne singulier - le pluriel (ou forme en vouvoiement) étant "quoi, dites ?"

Comment: @Greg Ah, la forme ***Quoi, dites ?*** existe ? Je ne l'ai jamais entendue. La virgule m'étonne car je n'ai jamais perçu de pause entre *quoi* et *dis* donc ça se prononce pour moi comme ***Où ça ?***.

Comment: Je l'écris avec une virgule comme j'écrirais "c'est grand, dis !" mais c'est vrai que la pause est à peine perceptible, voire inexistante. Le pluriel est plus rare (il faut alors une situation où on s'adresse à plusieurs personnes qui auraient la même requête), et le vouvoiement également sans doute parce que "quoi, dis ?" est familier et donc moins cohérent avec le niveau de politesse lié au vouvoiement, mais il existe parfaitement. Si j'adressais un "quoi, dis ?" au lieu de "quoi, dites" à quelqu'un que je vouvoie, j'aurais l'impression de faire montre d'impolitesse en passant au tutoiement.